# R converting dbf files to excel files xls

Tags: r, excel, loops, dbf

I can trying to read in all the dbf files in a folder and convert them excel files. below is the code i am working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(foreign)
library (rio)
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\tichamb\\Desktop\\New folder", pattern="*.dbf", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
for (files in "C:\\Users\\tichamb\\Desktop\\New folder")
  read.dbf(1001001, dbf)
  import (1001001, dbf)
  convert (1001001.dbf,"1001001.xls)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you made a `for` loop before? you need something like `for(file in files) {...`, and you really should have some reference to that `file` object in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Per user vignettes from RIO, you can't convert to xls, but you can convert to xlsx: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html.

```
library(rio)
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\tichamb\\Desktop\\New folder", pattern="*.dbf", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

for(i in files) {
  oldFile <- i
  sub(".dbf",".xlsx",i)
  convert(oldFile, i)
}
```

Comment: ".dbf" should already be appended to the input file `i` value, so you shouldn't need the `paste0` call there. You would need to adjust `i` for the output name though, for which `sub(".dbf",".xlsx",i)` should work.